# Is it possible to stir-fry meat cutlets without "oil bombing" ?)

Tags: meat, stir-fry

While frying in the pan, meat gives out the moisture, that causes oil to "shoot".

How do you make cutlets? And is there something, that I can add to the meat, to make water stay inside or go out slower? I've tried to add dry bread to meat, but it doesn't help. Maybe egg?

Comment: Question is closed so I can't answer. I make cutlets with about 50% meat, 40% mixture of onions and courgette, blended to a liquid with egg, salt, powdered white pepper, and 10% panko bread crumbs. The percentages are all by volume. My cutlets are quite liquid when raw; I cook in oil as quenelles or just patties; turning when lightly browned and then baking in a warm oven until fully cooked. Because I do not fully cook the cutlets in the oil, the liquid does not escape and cause much splattering.

Comment: By the way, "cutlet" is not a clearly defined term in all English locales. For instance, sometimes a cutlet is a lamb chop, other times a mechanically tenderized small joint of meat; whereas I assume in your question you are referring to the "frikacadelle" kind of cutlet.